# Loop through array and output links based on number of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

I currently have an array as follows:

```
   Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 34 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 35 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 36 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 37 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 1 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 38 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 1 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 39 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 1 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [id] => 40 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 2 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [id] => 41 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 2 )
    [8] => Array ( [id] => 42 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 2 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [id] => 43 [another_id] => 2805 [third_id] => 2 )
 )
```

What I need to do is ultimately print out 9 links ( as there are 9 array elements) but based on the keys in the array. For example:

```
www.samplelink/link/id/another_id/third_id
```

But I can't seem to get the loop right. What I have so far is:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
  foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    echo "<a>www.samplelink/link/".$key[$value]."</a>";
  }
}
```

But thats not exactly what I need as its printing out the keys as well. Anyone know what I could do?

Comment: "What I need to do is ultimately print out 9 links ( as there are 9 array elements)" noooo there are **10** !

Comment: First rule of programming: arrays start at 0

Comment: It took me about 10 minutes to realize I was counting my bills starting from 0, baffled each time

Comment: @Phiter no, it depends on the programming language! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list

Comment: Oh my god what the hell? People really don't know how to follow a standard, do they?

Comment: @Phiter there was meant to be another array at the end of that, thats why I specified 9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If elements in subarrays always in same order, you can just `implode` them:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo "<a>www.samplelink/link/".implode('/', $arr)."</a>";
}
```

Otherwise you should point what index will be in which position **explicitly**, as in **@Danyal Sandeelo**'s answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
 foreach ($array as $innerArray) {
  echo "<a>www.samplelink/link/".$innerArray['id']."/".$innerArray['another_id']."/".$innerArray['third_id']."</a>";
 }
```

It can give an `undefined index` error if key doesn't exist so you can do something like this as well:

```
foreach ($array as $innerArray) {
    $finalLink = array_key_exists('id',$innerArray)?$innerArray['id']:"";
    $finalLink.= "/".array_key_exists('another_id',$innerArray)?$innerArray['another_id']:"";
    $finalLink.= "/".array_key_exists('third_id',$innerArray)?$innerArray['third_id']:"";
    echo "<a>www.samplelink/link/$finalLink</a>";
}
```

Comment: When I'm not sure if the array key exists, I use this:  `$arr['key'] ?? ""`. It does the same as `isset()`, and doesn't throw an error. Of course this is PHP 7 only.

Comment: array key exists checks if the key exists within the array or not. In your case, it will crash if the array doesn't contain the key. For more info, read this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$arrays = array(
    "0" => array('id' => 30, 'another_id' => 2800, 'third_id' => 1),
    "1" => array('id' => 31, 'another_id' => 2801, 'third_id' => 1),
    "2" => array('id' => 32, 'another_id' => 2802, 'third_id' => 1),
    "3" => array('id' => 33, 'another_id' => 2803, 'third_id' => 1),
    "4" => array('id' => 34, 'another_id' => 2804, 'third_id' => 1),
    "5" => array('id' => 35, 'another_id' => 2805, 'third_id' => 2),
    "6" => array('id' => 36, 'another_id' => 2806, 'third_id' => 3),
    "7" => array('id' => 37, 'another_id' => 2807, 'third_id' => 3),
    "8" => array('id' => 38, 'another_id' => 2808, 'third_id' => 2),
    "9" => array('id' => 39, 'another_id' => 2809, 'third_id' => 2),
);

foreach($arrays as $key => $array) {
   echo 'www.samplelink/link/'.$array['id'].'/'.$array['another_id'].'/'.$array['third_id']. "\n";
}
```

you can play with it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c7838e25045263de03e23c60b19c86d5640407d

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo "<a>www.samplelink/link/" . $arr['id'] . '/' . $arr['another_id'] . '/' . $arr['third_id'] . "</a>";
}
```

or, if your sub-arrays always holds the ids in the proper order and nothing but the relevant ones :

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    echo "<a>www.samplelink/link/" . implode('/', $arr) . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$value` will hold the inner array on each iteration.

```
foreach($array as $value) {
  $link = '//www.samplelink/link/'.$value['id'].'/'.$value['another_id'].'/'.$value['third_id']
  echo '<a>'.$link.'</a>';
}
```